# Argument 1 must be type, not pygame.surface on super() call

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to build a pong game from scratch using Python, pygame, and OOP (I know, not the best language to use OOP).
currently have the following class structure:

gameObject(object) || Ball(gameObject) || Paddle(gameObject)

note: Ball extends gameObject

```
class gameObject:

def __init__(self, gameDisplay):
    (self.screenwidth, self.screenheight) = gameDisplay.get_size()
    self.gameDisplay = gameDisplay


class Ball(gameObject):

def __init__(self,x,y,r,speed,a, gameDisplay):
    super(gameDisplay)
    self.x = int(x)
    self.y = int(y)
    self.r = int(r)
    self.a = int(a)
    self.speed = speed
    self.xspeed = self.speed * math.cos(self.a)
    self.yspeed = self.speed * math.sin(self.a)
```

When I tried to create a ball, an error shows up:

super(gameDisplay)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not pygame.Surface

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `super` correctly.

`super().__init__(gameDisplay)`

This is in python3, since you do not inherit from `Object` I assumed python3

For more information on `super` see this [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)